# use tomcat6's manager to undeploy play app ,but failed

Tags: tomcat, playframework, tomcat-manager

We deploy our webapp  in tomcat6. it develop with play!framework.  we want to use tomcat6's manage to deploy or undeploy app.but undeploy failed,tomcat cant't delete app directory clean.because has a play.jar in using .i think because play.jar excuting a job...

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `antiResourceLocking` attribute of the webapp's `<Context>` element to `true`.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="true">
```

You can provide this in a `/META-INF/context.xml` file. See also [this documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html).